# Dir list of sub folder names

Tags: windows-7

I want to use a .bat file that executes the .dir command to create a list of all folders in all subfolders  of the current folder.

==========================
I am close:
I use:
dir /s /b /o:n /a:d >list.txt

to get the list of folders along with the full path.

...but I want the list with the folder names only, without the fullpath.

Is that possible?

Comment: If you don't mind using PowerShell, you can use `Get-ChildItem -Directory -Path "C:\temp"`.

Comment: @shinjijai : you would have to add  `-recurse` to answer the question...

Comment: If a PowerShell solution is acceptable, then use `(Get-ChildItem -Directory -Recurse -Path ".").Name | Set-Content -Path "list.txt"`. If only classic BAT is acceptable, it's possible - but complicated.

Comment: @K7AAY `FOR /F %I IN ('DIR /B /S /A:D') DO @ECHO %~NXI` only fails for paths that have spaces in them. If I wanted to _really_ dig into `FOR`, I could probably solve that problem as well. But I'm a PowerShell guy; it's just more ... well, _powerful_.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Add `"tokens=*"` after `/F` to fix the space problem. Use that and convert your comment into an answer :)

Comment: @DavidPostill - !!!!

Comment: @JeffZeitlin ???

Comment: @DavidPostill - Never really got the hang of "tokens=..."; had to try it - and was subsequently astonished at how easy the "complicated" turned out to be... :)

Answer (score 1):

With a little help from [David Postill](https://superuser.com/users/337631/davidpostill), you can do this with

```
(for /f "tokens=*" %I in ('dir /b /s /a:d') do @echo %~nxI) | sort > list.txt
```

to store the sorted list in the file. I guess it wasn't so complicated after all. :)

*(I still prefer the PowerShell solution, though...)*